# Newtons Method with an unknown method

Tags: functions, newton-raphson

I am attempting to use Newtons method in an optimisation problem. I haven't used Newtons method since my college days and after refreshing my memory I am encountering the following challenge. Basically I have observation data point and a model to simulate the same point. There is a single coefficient I can tune to make the model more similar to the observation. Rather than tune it manually, I want to use something more efficient. I was thus recommended Newtons method. So using newtons method I make an initial guess of the coefficient and get an initial answer, I compare this against the observed result and get my initial error. So the next step is to find the tangent to the curve at that point, in order to find my second estimate. With the function being unknown it seems impossible to find the tangent? What should I do? The only solution that comes to mind is instead of making 1 single intitial guess, I have to make 3 guess’s and fit a function to them, and as I proceed, continue fitting functions to more and more points. is this the correct manner?

Comment: How long does it take to test a single coefficient value?

Comment: Currently its 2 hours, but I will reduce the simulation time to 30 minutes by slightly reducing the accuracy. The 2 hour simulation model is already a simplification of a 24 hour processing time model, I will use each models answer to get a better starting guess for the next higher fidelity model

Comment: You could take a look at the secant method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate the tangent's gradient at the point $x$ with parameter $p$ using a finite difference approximation:

$f'(x,p) \approx \frac{f(x,p+h)-f(x,p)}{h}$.

This will involve evaluating your unknown function $f$ at two points. You can choose $h$ to be a reasonably small number. If it is small enough, the approximation will work.

These evaluations will take a long time to do. Is there are a way you do two or more evaluations in parallel?

Comment: So  I make two initial guesses that are very close and "h" distance apart. On every iteration do I make two guesses? I have to figure out if I can code a way to run in parallel. The simulation software is a commercial software that allows parallel processing when run internally. I haven't seen anything about running parallel processing externally. I have over 100 cases of these to solve so I may be able to run multiple different cases in parallel, optimising time

Comment: Yes. You should record what the gradients are at various points for reuse. Then you use the guess $f(x,p)$ in Newton's method as well. So yes in total two guesses.

Comment: Ok thank you, so on every iteration I only use the two previous guesses to find the new gradient. What will happen if my error never reaches zero?

Comment: That means the method doesn't converge. You may want to choose $h$ smaller, but in reality it would mean that your function $f$ is badly behaved - i.e. non convex, nonlinear, with many local minima to get trapped in.

However, Newton's method converges quadratically, which is very appealing in your case, as it could mean significantly fewer iterations.

Comment: Ok, thanks a million! I am going to code up a version for the 30 minute model and leave it run wild for the weekend.